# (useless?) Resource__ classes with jsonschema2pojo

Tags: java, json, jsonschema2pojo

Familiar with Java and XML, I have tried to process JSON data.
I'm using [jsonschema2pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) to generate Plain Old Java Objects from example JSON data.

Let's say I want to import products and categories from a webshop;

http://developers.seoshop.com/api/resources/product
http://developers.seoshop.com/api/resources/category

[jsonschema2pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) does its job, but what about all generated `Resource, Resource_, Resource__, Resource____` etc. files?

[image]

All these `Resource` classes are equal.
Can I just delete these (and replace them bij one `Resource` class)?
What is the reason for all these duplicated classes?

(*don't mind the .json and .schema.json file they're just for investigation*)

Answer (score 0):

If you have nested classes you can modify the ObjectRule.java and RuleFactory.java a bit. I created a Hash of Class Name, JSON node and the package using MD5 algorithm and stored it in a map. Before creating any new class I just check if it's hash already exists in the hashMap in which case I just return the class corresponding to that hash.

```
Check my commit here : mdfaizanali786/jsonschema2pojo@e5343db#diff-7fef584364765f2bd47a596ad18cecc4
```

If you have top level duplicate classes you can fetch the schema, jsonify it and then again do similar check that it is not identical.